# How to make Intellij to show the hints and suggestions automatically?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to make Intellij to show the hints suggestions without pressing any shortcuts. On selection, it used to suggest to add Exception on method signature / catch the exception.  For some reason it is not working now for Java 12. (it works fine with JDK 8)

Is there any way to make it work?

[image]

[image]

---

With Java 8 settings, I get this which is what I want for Java 12.

[image]

Comment: Is the issue reproduced for you with IDEA 2019.1.3 (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2019.1+EAP)?

Comment: Yes. I was able to replicate with new version as well.

Comment: Seems to be the bug, please create an issue report at YouTrack (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com) providing the idea.log files (Help | Show log in Finder). Thank you